# MERN, insert elements from a dynamic list to an array

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, arraylist, mern

Hello I am trying to make an array based on my data, I used MongoDB, actually trying to add _id into an array. If there already the _id exists then it will not add, I mean it will not repeat, as it is a dynamic list of data I make a loop but when I click to add data it always gives a new array for just one element and not adding new one. I have tried in many ways and hope anyone can help.

**Data:**

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("64d28f3abdc16189260a5521"),
    blood: "A+",
    birth: "2023-08-05",
    role: "student",
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("64d2edb9d0f86e45a48611b5"),
    blood: "B+",
    birth: "2013-08-05",
    role: "student",
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("64d2fd40d0f86e45a48611b8"),
    blood: "A+",
    birth: "2023-08-05",
    role: "student",
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("64d54434a2d26fwdsb83d12ab"),
    blood: "AB+",
    birth: "2013-06-05",
    role: "student",
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("64d48526b43hga0b83d12ab"),
    blood: "A+",
    birth: "2023-08-05",
    role: "student",
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("64d48526bd26fwdsb23sa12ab"),
    blood: "B+",
    birth: "2013-08-05",
    role: "student",
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("64d48343bd26faa0b83d12ab"),
    blood: "A+",
    birth: "2023-08-05",
    role: "student",
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("64d54434a2d26fwdsb83d12ab"),
    blood: "AB+",
    birth: "2013-06-05",
    role: "student",
  },
];
```

**Code:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Col, Container, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./ArrayManipulationComponent.css"; // Import your CSS file

const StudentGrid = ({ student }) => {
  const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);
  const { name, birth, _id } = student;

  const handleButtonClick = (_id) => {
    if (elements.includes(_id)) {
      const updatedElements = elements.filter(id => id !== _id);
      setElements(updatedElements);
    } else {
      setElements([...elements, _id]);
    }
  };

  console.log(elements);


  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col md={12}>
       
              <div>
              <p>
                <button
                  className={
                    elements.includes(_id) ? "active-button" : "action-button"
                  }
                  onClick={() => handleButtonClick(_id)}
                >
                  Button {_id}
                </button>
              </p>
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default StudentGrid;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your description mentioned above could not explain what exactly your problem is. Can you please share the code what described your error include console.log you are printing? And you are saying your problem is on the React.js FE, or MongoDB?

Comment: @ClusterH, those Data is for students ({student}), here is _id, I want to make a list of student who is attending the class, so when I click on the button I want to add the person id to an array so that I can send it to the database, so there can be multiple students and the array elements can be multiple but don't repeat same element, so I have tried with those functions to make this, it inserts _id, but when I click for the next student it doesn't add instead it sends new array of only one element, I am adding my front-page pic, please let me know if you want anything to know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared a `StudentGrid` component which is for 1 student info only, but therefore you somehow are trying to update a list of students.

This should be done in a parent component.

So I guess in your parent component there is a code similar to this

`students.map(studentInfo => <StudentGrid info={studentInfo} />`

This is where you should put the state for selected elements

`const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);`

and then when clicking the button inside the `StudentGrid` you should handle that action inside your parent component where the full list is kept in state.

So

```
           <button
              className={
                elements.includes(_id) ? "active-button" : "action-button"
              }
              onClick={() => props.handleButtonClick(_id)}
            >
              Button {_id}
            </button>
```

and then inside your parent component something like that

```
<StudentGrid info={studentInfo} handleButtonClick={parentComponentHandleClick} />
```